# iPhone can't connect to fiddler proxy server

Tags: proxy, fiddler, windows-firewall, windows-server-2016

I have been debugging my software by connecting an iphone which is on the same network. Then I use fiddler on my desktop/server and set it to Allow Remote Connection (instructions [here](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/using-fiddler-with-apple-ios-devices)). I had this configuration working under Windows Server 2012, since I've upgraded my server to Server 2016 I am no longer able to get the phone to connect to the proxy server at xx.xx.xx.xx:8888. I checked "Allowed Apps" in the Windows Firewall but I don't see anything that looks relevant in there.

I am able to connect to the web server I have running on my server 2016 from my phone so they are able to talk to each other.  I just can't access the fiddler proxy server.

Fiddler says it is online and appears to be working correctly.

I'm using Fiddler v4.6.20171.7553.

Is there some setting in windows firewall that might be blocking my proxy server connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I changed the firewall settings in Windows firewall to ask me if an app was going to be blocked.  After restarting fiddler I was prompted and I said yes, allow this app to go through the firewall and then it started working.